# Convert buffer repesents list of int little indian Python class

Tags: python, c, struct, buffer

I'm trying to get data from buffer represents as string,

Example:

got :

```
str = "0004000001000000020000000A000000"


class MyData:
    length
    some_data
    array_data
    buf_data

data = parse(str)
```

Except :

```
length=1024, some_data=1, array_data=[2,10], buf_data="000000020000010"
```

Explain:

length=1024 since the 8 numbers "00040000" repesnts an hex number in little indian

and the rest the same idea,
"00040000  01000000  0200000  00A000000"

1024, 1, 2, 10

any idea?

I have some solution but it's too messy and isn't easy to support

Comment: Instead of describing your code, please [edit] your question and show your (possibly incomplete) code, preferably as a [mre].

Comment: FWIW, those little-endian hex numbers `00040000`, `01000000`, `02000000`, and `0A000000` look like 16384, 16, 32, and 160 to me.

Comment: @SteveSummit Maybe, but this is how I get my data after I use print("%02X", DATA) every byte from the whole buffer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

```
class MyData:
    mmap = [16**1, 16**0, 16**3, 16**2, 16**5, 16**4, 16**7, 16**6]
    def __init__(self, buffer):
        self.buffer = buffer
        self.integers = []
    def get_integers(self):
        if len(self.integers) == 0:
            for i in range(0, len(self.buffer), 8):
                a = 0
                for x, y in zip(self.buffer[i:i+8], self.mmap):
                    a += int(x, 16) * y
                self.integers.append(a)
        return self.integers

mydata = MyData('0004000001000000020000000A000000')

print(mydata.get_integers())
```

**Output:**

```
[1024, 1, 2, 10]
```

NOTE: This is specifically for 32-bit unsigned values

Comment: Very nice ! I'm wondering if there is some module maybe struct module ? since in this way it will be something like that : a=func, b = func, c=func, or at least there is some way to initial all the members of the class in some for loop ?

Comment: @Itamar perhaps you could rephrase that. I'm not quite sure what you need

Comment: I need to extract the values into my class nicely and flat style and avoid doing "hard coded" assign to every member

Comment: OK - What does your class look like?

Comment: class MyData:
    length,   some_data1   ,   some_data2,     some_data3, 
    
    array_data, 
    buf_data

Comment: in my question it's more clear, I have several int members and an array of int and its buffer after "fix" the buffer

Comment: I've edited the Answer. Maybe that's what you wanted. I won't be doing any more work on this